# To highlight selected item after component refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-services

**SCENARIO:** I have component called `list`, which display  all `customers` in the list. In this list I have written conditions like this:

1) By default 1st `list-item(Ex customer 1)` will be selected and that selected `list-item(Ex customer 1)` will be emitted to another component called `display`.

2) Then on clicking any  `list-item(i,e customer)` the selected list item also emitted `display` component. As in the below images:

[image]
[image]

**contact-list component code:**

**HTML**

```
<mat-selection-list>
    <mat-list-option [ngClass]="{selected : currentContact && contact.Name == currentContact.Name}" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
           <a mat-list-item (click)="onSelect(contact)">{{ contact.Name }} </a>
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component Input,EventEmitter,Output} from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer} from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'drt-customers-list',
  templateUrl: './customers-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers-list.component.scss'],
})
export class CustomerListComponent {
 public customers:  ICustomer[] ;
   public currentContact: IContact;
 @Output()
 public select = new EventEmitter();

 constructor(public customersService: CustomersService,) {}

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.customers = await this.customersService.getCustomersList('');
    this.customerRefreshed();
  }

   public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {===>To emit 1st contact by default
    if (this.contacts && this.contacts.length > 0) {
    this.currentContact = this.contacts[0];
    this.select.emit(this.currentContact);
    }
   }

  public customerRefreshed() { ====> To refresh the list after updating
    this.customersService.customerUpdated.subscribe((data: boolean) => {
        if(data) {
            this.customers = await this.customersService.getCustomersList('');
        }
    });  

  }

  public onSelect(contact: IContact): void {===> To emit contact on click
    this.select.emit(contact);
  }


}
```

Now i have another component to `update the contacts`, There i will update selected `contact` by performing `PUT` operation then i will refresh the `contact-list` again.To see the changes.

**update-contact component code:**

```
public updateCustomer(): void {
    this.someCustomer = this.updateForm.value;
    this.customersService.UpdateCustomer(this.someCustomer, this.someCustomer.id).subscribe(
      () => {  // If POST is success
        this.customersService.customerUpdated.next(true);
        this.successMessage();
      },
      (error) => {  // If POST is failed
        this.failureMessage();
      }
    );
  }
```

**services file:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer} from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CustomersService {
 private  baseUrl : string = '....Url....';
 public  customerUpdated: Subject<boolean>;


  constructor() {
    this.customerUpdated = new Subject<boolean>();
 }

  public async getCustomersList(): Promise<ICustomer[]> {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;
    return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
 }

  public UpdateCustomer(customer: ICustomer, id: string): Observable<object> {
     const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers/${id}`;
     return this.http.post(apiUrl, customer);
  }

}
```

Now the issues, Suppose if i `select/click` the 2nd `list-item(Customer 2)`  to update, Then after updating the `list-item(Customer 1)` is selected by default like this:

[image]

But after update the previously clicked `list-item(Customer 2)` must be in `selected` state again,**even after refreshing the `list` like this**:

[image]

Comment: How you configure your routes

Comment: There is no routing between `list` & `display` components, both `list` & `display` are the **children components** of another component called `customer`.

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz. So that it will be easy to test.

Answer (score 1):

After refresh the page no info will keep,

One way you can do that configure your routes like.

```
[{path:'list',component: ListComponent},
 chilren[
 {path:'list/:id',component: DetailsComponent}]
```

]

using Activated route firstchild params you can read the ROUTE related any information.

Second Way:  Use Local storages